# jquery fancybox popup call from parent javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, fancybox

> Can any one help me how to call fancybox popup from parent js file.
>   when i clik on button  it will one function if condition is true in
>   function i need to open fancybox popup. Advance thanks..

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#EXTERNAL").fancybox({
        'width'             : '80%',
        'height'            : '100%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'href'              : 'openpopup.html',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
       });
    function clickFancy(){
if(true){
// here i need open fancypopup
}else(){

}
<body>
<form name="frm1">
    <input type="submit" name="fancy" onclick="clickFancy()">
<button>Click me</button>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by parent js? What happens when you run this code? and What does your console say?

Comment: I saw you tried to edit my answer, but if you have any comments is better to use the comments area. If my solution doesn't work is because you may need to set a valid condition in `if (true)` .... I just copied your original script and I assumed (wrongly perhaps) that you were not literally evaluating that condition as is but just use it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you already initialized fancybox for this selector

```
$("#EXTERNAL").fancybox();
```

then just trigger a `click` within your function

```
function clickFancy() {
    if (true) {
        // here i need open fancypopup
        $("#EXTERNAL").trigger("click");
    } else {

    }
}
```

... then call that function from wherever you need to. BTW this `<button>Click me</button>` does nothing so I wonder why is there. Also, `else()` should be just `else` unless you are nesting another condition with `else if()`.

**EDIT** :

In response to your *edit* attempt, the function works as you can see is this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x8CbD/)**.

What I suspect (I mean no offense) is that you have some gaps in the knowledge of how selectors and javascript condition statements should work and how they are related to html elements.